# Asynchronous Callback functions: Iphone Versus Android

Tags: android, iphone

On Callback

On Iphone

### File A:

@protocol servicedelegate 
-(void)taskCompleted:(NSDcitionary*) dict;
@end

-(void) performtask
callback=@"taskCompleted:";

[(id)delegate performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(callback) withObject:data];

### File B:

-(void) taskcompleted:(NSDictionary*)dict
{

//don something when File A fisnihed the taskcompleted and have the data
// this callback on File B will be awaken from File A's delegate function
}

***The question How does Android implement the above, File A waiting to getting the data, and nobody knows how long, but once finished, File B would awaken by the delegate callback function of taskcompleted.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple different ways:

- [Handlers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)
- [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

I'm a fan of AsyncTask myself, but they require more boilerplate. Handlers can often be simpler.

Comment: I tend to find AsyncTask more reusable across projects